# Calculation with jQuery accordion slider plugin writing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, frontend

I'm trying to write jQuery plugin for making accordion.

All items inside the container need to reduce their width so all items could be shown on one line.

On item hover, rest of the items should reduce width so it the hover item could be shown at its original width.

The error occurs when trying to initial set the items: the last item disappears.
the math is:

```
slider-width / all-items-width
```

and then:

```
each-item * (slider-width / all-items-width)
```

What am I calculating wrong?

```
jQuery(function($) {

$.fn.shadeAccordion = function(elmwrap, sliderH) {

var $this = $(this), //get the slider countiner
  SlideR = $this,
  SliderWidth = SlideR.width(), // slider should inherit parent witdth
  thumbA = SlideR.find('a'), // images should wrap with a tag
  thumbMOunt = thumbA.length, // count the number of images
  thumbImg = thumbA.find('img'); // find  acctual imgaes

var imgaesWidth = 0;
thumbImg.each(function(index, el) {
  imgaesWidth += $(el).width();
});
console.log(imgaesWidth);
var margineach = SliderWidth / imgaesWidth;
console.log(margineach);

//some CSS Settigns
SlideR.find(elmwrap).css({
  'transition': 'width .2s ease-in',
  'height': sliderH,
  'overflow': 'hidden',
  'position': 'static'
}).find('img').css({
  height: sliderH,
  width: 'auto',
  'position': 'relative',
  'max-width': 'none'
});;

$.fn.HoverAnimation = function(SliderWidth) {
  var $this = $(this), //get the specific hoverd container
    imgWid = $this.data('orginalwidht'), //actual image width for this cont
    sliderWidthAfterOpen = SliderWidth - imgWid,
    thumbImgSibDiv = $this.siblings(elmwrap);


  var sibImgaesWidth = 0;
  thumbImgSibDiv.each(function(index, el) {
    sibImgaesWidth += $(el).width();
  });
  var margineachOpend = sliderWidthAfterOpen / sibImgaesWidth;


  $this.addClass('active').width(imgWid).css('opacity', '1');

  thumbImgSibDiv.addClass('inactive').each(function() {
    var thisW = $(this).width();
    $(this).width(thisW * margineachOpend).css('opacity', '0.4');
  });

}; //End of mouse over

$.fn.LeaveAnimation = function(SliderWidth) {
  var $this = $(this),
    imgWid = $this.data('editedwidth');

  $this.removeClass('active').width(imgWid);
  SlideR.find(elmwrap).css('opacity', '0.4').not('.active').removeClass('inactive').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).data('editedwidth'));
  }); //End of Each change Margin

}; //End of mouseleave

widhtS = 0;
// adjust new width and declare animation when hover
SlideR.find(elmwrap).each(function(idx, el) {
    var imgW = $(el).find('img').width();

    $(el).width(Math.round(imgW * margineach)); //change images width so they will super fit to the slider
    $(el).attr('data-orginalwidht', imgW).attr('data-editedwidth', Math.round(imgW * margineach)).find('img').css({
      margin: '0',
      padding: '0'
    });
    $(el).css({
      'margin': 0,
      'clear': 'none',
      'padding': 0
    }); //change images width so they will super fit to the slider
    widhtS += Math.round(imgW * margineach);
    console.log(Math.round(widhtS));
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).HoverAnimation(SliderWidth)
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).LeaveAnimation(SliderWidth)
  });

}

 });
```

heres a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/12345/8zd9nmvf/23/

Answer (score 0):

the issue was CSS - i was calculating all images width before their width became auto.

so i moved css properties up before the calculation and it fixed:

```
//some CSS Settigns
SlideR.find(elmwrap).css({
  'transition': 'width .2s ease-in',
  'height': sliderH,
  'overflow': 'hidden',
  'position': 'static'
}).find('img').css({
  height: sliderH,
  width: 'auto',
  'position': 'relative',
  'max-width': 'none'
});

var imgaesWidth = 0;
thumbImg.each(function(index, el) {
  imgaesWidth += $(el).width();
});
var margineach = SliderWidth / imgaesWidth;
```